# Different characters take more/less data?

Tags: text, byte, ascii

I am working on a personal project and I'm wondering if certain characters take up more data in a text file than others. I need to choose a character to seperate items in my file, but if a 0 uses less bytes than a ! or something, it would be best to do that. I know all characters have an ASCII value, but would a lower ASCII value mean the character can be stored in fewer bytes?

This might be an incredibly stupid question, but I don't see any information on the topic online so I came here to check.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not a stupid question. It is a odd and amusing question though. :)

Comment: @Nathan: Note that your programs are probably using the 127 ASCII characters.  If you want to support any other characters, the answers get a _lot_ more complicated.

Comment: I'm only using about 20 characters actually, all good there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on which character set you are using as to whether or not one character will take up more space than another.  Some character sets are variable-width [1]. UTF-8 is one such character set.  Using UTF-8 as an example, the standard ASCII characters are all 1 byte in width, whereas the extended ASCII characters start to take up multiple bytes (up to 6) [2].

In your example, of '0' and '!': both are standard ASCII and therefore both are 1 byte in width in UTF-8.

**References:**

1. [Variable Width Encoding (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-width_encoding)
2. [UTF-8 Description (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description)

Comment: Thank you for the information! Good to know I won't need to build up from ASCII[0] and up to conserve bytes or something :p

Comment: 2 minor nitpicks.  (1) "Extended ASCII" isn't a real thing, it's a pretend thing that has _nothing_ to do with Unicode.  (2) "In November 2003, UTF-8 was restricted by RFC 3629... This removed all 5- and 6-byte sequences, and about half of the 4-byte sequences." So the limit is now 4 bytes for a "codepoint".  I say "codepoint" and not "character", because "character" has like 1245342 definitions, and in almost all of them, a character may be composed of many codepoints.

Comment: UTF-8 is not a character set; It's one of several encodings for the Unicode character set.

Answer (score 1):

You can also test sizes of different characters by putting them in a file and checking the file size using `ls -l` or `stat -f "%N %z"` commands

```
test $cat a
0
test $cat b
!
test $cat c
ક
test $cat d
æ
test $stat -f "%N %z" *
a 2
b 2
c 4
d 3
test $ls -l 
total 32
-rw-r--r--  1 spundun  wheel  2 Jun  2 14:10 a
-rw-r--r--  1 spundun  wheel  2 Jun  2 14:10 b
-rw-r--r--  1 spundun  wheel  4 Jun  2 14:11 c
-rw-r--r--  1 spundun  wheel  3 Jun  2 14:13 d
test $
```

I believe each file has an extra byte to indicate end-of-file `EOF`. so the sizes of the characters are 1, 1, 3, 2 respectively.